# Как правильно записать в std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++

Мне  нужно в мапу histogram  записать значения. Я записываю,  но выдает ошибки. Как правильно  записать?

```
std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
for (const auto& histogramsThread : histograms)
    histogram.insert(std::make_pair(histogramsThread.cbegin(), histogramsThread.cend()), histogram.end());
```

UPD меина

```
int main() 
{
    auto text = ReadDataFromFile("D:\\text.txt");

    const auto textIntervals = GenerateIntervals(text);
    const auto usedThreadCount = textIntervals.size();

    std::vector<std::unordered_map<char, size_t>> 
    histograms(usedThreadCount);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(usedThreadCount);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < usedThreadCount; ++i)
       threads[i] = std::thread(BuildHistogram, std::cref(textIntervals[i]), 
          text, std::ref(histograms[i]));

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < usedThreadCount; ++i)
        threads[i].join();

    std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
    for (const auto& histogramsThread : histograms)
        histogram.insert(histogramsThread);

   for (int ch = 0; ch < 256; ++ch) 
   {
        if (text[ch]) 
         {
              std::cout << "Character '" << char(ch) << "' occurs " << 
   text[ch] << " times\n";
         }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что именно записать? У вас в вопросе приведен вырванный из контекста бессмысленный огрызок кода, из которого совершенно ничего не ясно.

Comment: const auto& histogramsThread : histograms и как же это понимать? думаю стоит прочитать это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: У меня есть мапа histogram . Я в нее  хочу  записать значенния с  histograms, для этого я использую переменую histogramsThread. Как мне правильно записать? Что ту  не понятного в моем вопросе?!

Comment: Ничего непонятно в вашем вопросе. Что такое histograms? Какой его тип? Какую задачу вы хотите решить?(другими словами что вы хотите сделать)

Comment: std::vector<std::unordered_map<char, size_t>> histograms вектор, в который я записала мапы. И тепепрь эти мапы мне нужно записать в одну мапу. вернее, все что в  этих мпах мне  нужно  переписать в  одну мапу

Comment: @Оксана Волинець: С чего вы взяли что в вашу "мапу histogram" вообще в принципе можно записать эти значения?

Comment: @AnT так мне  нужно  туда  записать. правильно  ли я  записываю,  вот это  другой вопрос)

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, вы пытаетесь в `unordered_map<char, size_t>` вставить другой `unordered_map<char, size_t>` через `insert`. А туда можно вставить только `std::pair<char, size_t>`. Вы забыли вложенный цикл внутри `for (const auto& histogramsThread : histograms)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
{
    histogram.insert(make_pair(c,c*c));
}
```

Вот такое отлично работает.

Но вряд ли у вас в

```
std::make_pair(histogramsThread.cbegin(), histogramsThread.cend())
```

`cbegin()` дает `char`, а `cend()` - `size_t`. Скорее всего, вы как-то не так понимаете работу итераторов или `make_pair`. А может, и `unordered_map`...

Comment: может  быть. Я  хотела дипазон с маленьких мап  записать в конец в главную мапу.  Тоесть мне  нужно с мап histograms все  записать в  главную мапу histogram. Как  это сделать?

Comment: Ну, типа `for(auto v: histogram) histograms.insert(v)` - что-то вроде этого.

Comment: std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
 for (const auto& histogramsThread : histograms)
  histogram.insert(histogramsThread);

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  no instance of overloaded function "std::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=char, _Ty=size_t, _Hasher=std::hash<char>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const char, size_t>>]" matches the argument list

Comment: Я же не знаю, что там у вас! В вопросе нет ни слова о типе histogram - поенятно, ято я предположил, что это `map<char,size_t>`. Вы, когда спрашиваете, давайте полную информацию. А то - доктор, у меня кое-что болит, лечите? - И что у вас болит? - Не ваше дело, ваше дело - лечить!... :)

Comment: выложила свой main где  делаю многопоточность и где мне и нужна помощь в  додавании

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы не до конца разобрались в типах контейнеров, которые вы используете. У вас есть `std::vector`, хранящий в себе `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>`. Соответственно, **каждый элемент `std::vector` является `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>`**. А теперь давайте посмотрим на ваш код:

```
std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
for (const auto& histogramsThread : histograms)
    histogram.insert(histogramsThread);
```

Вы пробегаете по `std::vector<std::unordered_map<char, size_t> >` и каждый его элемент пытаетесь положить в обычный `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>`. На лицо несовпадение типов, т.к. `insert` у `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>` ожидает в качестве параметра `std::pair<char, size_t>`, а не другой `std::unordered_map`.

На вашем месте я бы избегал пользоваться `auto` до тех пор, пока вы не будете полностью понимать, какой тип будет при использовании данной операции.

Вот простой пример на основании вашего кода, который перебирает все `unordered_map` в `vector` и кладет каждую `pair` в итоговый `unordered_map`:

```
// Create final unordered map
std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
for (const auto &hist : histograms) {
    // hist is std::unordered_map<char, size_t> &
    for (const auto &pair : hist) {
        // pair is std::pair<char, size_t> &
        // which we now can insert into our final map
        histogram.insert(pair);
    }
}
```

Внимательно следите за типами данных.

Comment: не совсем так, мне надо вставить(insert) если первый раз
или добавить к тому что уже было  вставлено
если такие ключ-значение уже вставлены.  У меня есть  текст, мне нужно пощитать сколько раз символ встречается в  тексте. Я расбиваю на потоки, потоки записываю  в мапы.  и Теперь мне нужно все маленькие мапы записать в  главную мапу. И поэтому мне нужно уже учитывать а был ли уже этот символ записан.

Comment: И суму символов  еще учитывать. Но я не  знаю как это реализовать (